# Autocovariance of a particular process, tX

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes

Given the following stochastic process:

$$Y_t = t X$$

where: $E(X)=0$ and $VAR(X) = 1 $.

Is it correct to obtain the autocovariance in the following way?

$$COV(Y_t, Y_s) = E [Y_tY_s] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{since, $E[X_t] = 0$.}$$

$$E [Y_tY_s]=E[tXsX] = tsE[X^2] = tsVAR(X) = ts$$

Others say me that the correct way is:

$$E [Y_tY_s]=E[tXsX] = tE[X]sE[X] = 0$$

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way is correct.
\begin{eqnarray}
Cov(Y_t,Y_s) &=& E[Y_t\cdot Y_s]-E[Y_t]\cdot E[Y_s] \\
&=& E[tX\cdot sX]-E[tX]\cdot E[sX] \\
&=& tsE[X^2]-ts(E[X])^2 \\
&=& tsE[X^2] \\
&=& ts(Var[X]-E[X]^2) \\
&=& ts(1-0^2) \\
&=& ts
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Perhaps something to note too is that this process is not stationary, and an auto-covariance function that depends only on the lag (i.e. $t-s$) does not exist.